# What is the "frequency of occurrence" referring to in this paper?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

In Zhou et al.(2018) 22. 10.1016/j.geoderma.2018.02.015, table 1 of the different microplastics refer to a "frequency of occurence".

[image]

Why does the % frequency of occurrence add up to >100% ? What is the difference between frequency of occurrence and proportion ?

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323593126_The_distribution_and_morphology_of_microplastics_in_coastal_soils_adjacent_to_the_Bohai_Sea_and_the_Yellow_Sea

Comment: Presumably it’s the percentage of sampling sites that contained any amount of the given size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask:

> Why does the % frequency of occurrence add up to >100% ?

It's an aggregate binary (yes/no) statistic - "at the sampling sites [plural]" - which tells you how many times ("frequency") items in the 7 classes show up ("occur") in the total sample population (here, 120 samples from 53 sites, 6360 samples).

So, at 32% of the sites, we find pellets; and at 43.4% of sites, we find sponges. It doesn't tell us *which* of the sites in particular but it does yield information about overall prevalence of certain type of microplastics at the sites.

The reason the sum is not 100% is because the numbers are not normalized. All they tell us is that at 32% of the 53 sites, we found pellets. At 43.4% of the 53 sites, we found sponges. And so on for the remaining 5 classes.

> What is the difference between frequency of occurrence and proportion ?

The former is "does something in this class appear here (yes or no, not how many);" the latter is "of the total number of things collected here, take the number of things in each class and divide that number by the total and multiply the result by 100%."

So we see that pellets appear at about a third of the sites (32%). However, they account for only a very small percentage of the overall amount of microplastics at only 0.1%. Foams and flakes show up at a lot of sites *and* comprise large amounts of the types of detritus at those sites.